# troubles using my splited date data on a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a date picker that throws me a selected date, I need split this date on month, day and year so I can consult another user data, I could split it correctly and the console.log shows the correct day, month and year, the problem is that I don't know how to use them in a function. It throws undefined when I use them on a function.

this is my code

```js
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';
const PersonalForm = ({onSubmit, errorMessage}) => {
    const [vBirthDate, setvBirthDate] = useState('');
    const [month, day, year] = vBirthDate.split('/')
    console.log(`Month: ${month}`)
    console.log(`Day: ${day}`)
    console.log(`Year: ${year}`)

    const RFC = () => {
        console.log(vName, 
        vSecondName, 
        vLastName, 
        vSecondLastName, 
        vBirthDate,
        vBirthDate.day,
         month,
        `Month: ${month}`, 
        `Day: ${day}`, 
        `Year: ${year}`);
        }
             return ( 
        <ScrollView>

        <View style={styles.containerdate}>
                <DatePicker 
                  date={vBirthDate} //initial date from state
                  mode="date" //The enum of date, datetime and time
                  placeholder="select date"
                  format="DD/MM/YYYY"
                  minDate="01/01/1900"
                  maxDate="01/01/2019"
                  confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                  cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                  androidMode="spinner"
                  customStyles={{
                    placeholderText: {
                      fontSize: 16,
                    },
                    dateIcon: {
                      height: 0,
                      width: 0,
                    },
                    dateText: {
                      color: '#b3b4b5',
                      fontSize: 16,
                    },
                    dateInput: {
                      borderWidth: 0,
                    }
                  }}
                  onDateChange={(date) => {setvBirthDate(date);RFC();} }
                />
              </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};
```

The functions RFC prints everything right except the dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In on change event, pass "date" as argument to RFC method.

```
onDateChange={ (date) => { setvBirthDate(date); RFC(date); } }
```

2) Update the RFC method with argument

```
const [splitDate, setSplitDate] = useState({});
const RFC = (date) => {
    const [month, day, year] = vBirthDate.split('/');
    // Now, if needed you can save to state
    setSplitDate({ month, day, year });
    console.log(`Month: ${month}`, `Day: ${day}`, `Year: ${year}`);
}
```